# apache2 throws the 500 error every time I restart the server (Python Django project)

Tags: python, django, apache2

I have a problem with my apache 2 server. Apparantly the problem was in the wsgi.py file connection because when I changed the DEBUG variable to true ,nothing changed. Here is my .conf file:

```js
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/me/projectfolder/static
    <Directory /home/me/projectfolder/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/me/projectfolder/media
    <Directory /home/me/projectfolder/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/me/projectfolder/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/me/projectfolder/myproject/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/me/projectfolder python-home=/home/me/projectfolder/venv
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Anyway thanks for help.